# Node.js Log out of steam bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, logout, steambot

Idk if this has been asked before, I tried searching it but didn't find anything.

I am making a steam comment bot so I have multiple accounts that I want to sign into.
I am using Node.js to do the magic and this is how I log in (which works fine):

```
client.logOn(CreateNewLogin(index));

client.on("loggedOn", () => {
    console.log("comment");
    //sign out?
}

function CreateNewLogin(index)
{
    var loginOptions = 
    {
        accountName: config.accountName[index],
        password: config.password[index]
    }
    return loginOptions
};
```

only issue is that if I do another client.logOn now the old one is still active and it returns an error, so how in hell do I logout the old one?

I found this which is pretty usefull for most of the stuff I am doing but sadly doesn't contain what I am looking for rn: [Link](https://github.com/DoctorMcKay/node-steamcommunity/wiki/CSteamUser#commentmessage-callback)

Answer (score 0):

Nvm just figgured out you can use   `client.logOff();`